# Can I use the <%: tag on an application that will be hosted on IIS6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, html.encode

Can I use the <%: tag on an application that will be hosted on IIS6? What about on an application targeted for .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%:` is an asp.net 4.0 feature, so targeting 3.5 means you can't use it.

You can however, host .net 4.0 on IIS 6.

Comment: What about an  application that use the 4.0 framework but is hosted on IIS6?

Answer (score 2):

**YES** to .Net 4.0 on IIS6. **NO** to 3.5